# Pixels different sizes in different server environments

Tags: html, css, local, pixel

I've been working on a site in a MAMP environment and recently uploaded it onto a hosting server to do cross-browser testing and noticed something weird. The page is literally larger -- not that the container has changed pixel size (Chrome's "Inspect Element" says it is 940px wide in both instances) but if I flip between a tab in the local environment and a tab with the server environment, it is literally visually larger. 940px means a larger screen distance on the server, evidently.

Everything seems to be resized to the same ratio so it hasn't affected the layout at all, so I'm not exactly *troubled* by this, but I am sort of puzzled. Does anyone know why this is happening and if I should be doing anything in particular about it?

Comment: You accidentally clicked control-wheel-up on one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you haven't "zoomed in" to the page?

Press cmd+0 to make sure you are at 100% zoom level... (I guess it's just ctrl+0 on Windows)

Another reason could be that a monitor has a different resolution...

Comment: He said he's looking at two different tabs, not two different monitors.  I agree, he probably zoomed in on the one page.

Answer (score 0):

That is because of different screen-resolutions, or because you have zoomed the chrome-window.